# Unknown error when running program

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Basically, I keep on getting this error when I run my app (even though there's no code in the ViewController.m). I don't see what could be causing it. Could someone please explain whats going on? Thanks.

[image: Here is the error I got]

Comment: Could you provide more details? Did you try using **Exception Breakpoint**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here i attach image show the exception break point please as per show image perform action and let me know what is the error going on.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I don't know exactly what I did. But after I clicked on that button / played around with it, my error went away. I have no idea why it worked, but it just did.

Comment: Listen it's exception debug point you added "Add exception breakpoint".

Comment: @dabomb It's possible that you had rogue breakpoints in your code by accident. That's why your error says "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1"

Answer (score 1):

edit - The actual answer is at the bottom, but my original answer does contain some helpful information for you, so I will leave it.

That is the line of code that is executed when the app is finished running, so from the information you've given alone, this could literally be any error that causes the app to crash.

Look down near the bottom, and you'll see a button that looks kind of like |>, right next to the blue breakpoint. If you press that a couple times, the debugging console will fill up with some text, which will tell us more about your error.  My best guess is that you're getting an unspecified selector send to instance, which means you're trying to call a method that doesn't exist for the given object.  This often means that an object is not set to the type that you think it is.  Perhaps a view controller is still of type UIViewController, but you intended to set it as ViewController?

Show us more info about the error for more specific help.

edit - You accidentally added a breakpoint at that line, which is the blue bar at the edge of your text editor at the highlighted line.  Click and drag the break point icon off of the text editor and it will disappear.  Clicking on the edge of the text editor adds a breakpoint, which will pause your app whenever that line of code is executed.

Comment: On top of this. If you add an "Exception Breakpoint", you can pinpoint where exactly in your code this occurs.

Comment: @MCKapur I'd definitely recommend exception breakpoints for testing, but I've found that they don't always get triggered when an app crashes.  However, there is almost always information describing your crash in the console, albeit hard to decipher sometimes.